# jQuery Tablesorter Filter: Use only one filter search box for entire table?

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

I'm using Tablesorter Filter to filter results in a multi-column table. Currently, each column has its own filter search box, which you can see in the [demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html). What I'm wondering is, is it possible to have only a single filter search box that filters for every column, like what's possible in the DataTables plugin (seen [here](http://datatables.net/index))?

Answer (score 1):

Use this [quicksearch plugin](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) with tablesorter. It should be initialized as follows:

```
$('#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr');
```

If you need to use it with the pager plugin, then you'll need this initialization code:

```
$('#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr', {
    delay: 500,
    show: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('filtered');
        $table.trigger('pageSet'); // reset to page 1 & update display
    },
    hide: function () {
        $(this).hide().addClass('filtered');
        $table.trigger('pageSet'); // reset to page 1 & update display
    },
    onAfter: function () {
        // no need to update the table, just the pager, so use its namespace
        $table.trigger('update.pager');
    }
});
```

Someday I'll build this into a widget, but in the mean time watch for updates in [this issue thread](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/114).